# Using output of one select query as input for another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an employee table which includes `ManagerID` as a `foreign key`. To get the currently logged `ManagerId` on `Employees`, I use a statement like -

```
SELECT MgrId FROM Employees WHERE EmpId=@EmpId
```

`@EmpId` is currently Logged on `Employees`.

I need to get the currently logged on employees manager and the manager's manager in one statement. This involves using the output of the above statement as input of another select statement. I am unsure how to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Look up for CTE : you'll do something like "With Manager (man) as (select MgrId from Employees WHERE EmpId=@EmpId) " then you can use the column man as a criteria in the following statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Employee ID field is named `Id`

```
SELECT e.Id [EmployeeId], e.MgrId [ManagerId], m.MgrId [ManagerManagerId]
FROM Employees e
LEFT JOIN Employees m ON e.MgrId = m.Id
WHERE e.EmpId=@EmpId
```